# Using integral test for $\sum 1/i^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

It's been a while since I've done an Integral, but am required to relearn them for a class. Could anyone help me with the integral of $\dfrac{1}{i^2}$? Wouldn't the answer be $-1/i$ ?

#### Context

I'm trying to use the integral test for the summation $\sum_{i=1 }^n   1/i^2$. 
I'm trying to show that that summation is bounded above by a constant, so I'm using the integral test to do it. I'm just having trouble integrating $1/i^2$.

Comment: What are you integrating with respect to? This is a maths site, so if you're using $i$ as a variable, rather than a number, you have to make it clear somehow!

Comment: Is "i" a variable here, or just the square root of -1?  If it's the number, you will just be integrating a constant.

Comment: Well i'm trying to use the integral test for the summation from i=1 to n of 1/i^2

Comment: What are you asking, EXACTLY?

Comment: I'm trying to show that that summation is bounded above by a constant, so I'm using the integral test to do it. I'm just having trouble integrating 1/i^2

Answer (score 1):

For another upper bound on the partial sums, note that
$$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}\le 1+\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)\cdot n}.\tag{1}$$

In general we have $\frac{1}{(k-1)\cdot k}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$. Thus 
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)\cdot n}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}.\tag{2}$$
There is mass cancellation (telescoping) in (2). It simplifies to $\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{n}$.

Thus the left side of (1) is less than or equal to $2-\frac{1}{n}$. It follows that all partial sums are $\lt 2$. Now we have our bound.

Answer (score 0):

so the power rules is: $\int x^n dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, which holds for every number $n$, with the exception of $n=-1$. In this case, you have $\int i^{-2} di$ Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: Yes, so the answer is -1/i?